# Comparing string representation of object to string representation of each object in a list

Tags: python, oop

Is there a simple way of comparing the string representation of an object to each object in a list?

The example code below (Python 2.7) works as intended, but I assume there's a much nicer way of doing this in Python!

```
class url(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
       self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

list_of_urls = [url('http://www.example.foo'), url('http://www.example.bar')]
test_url = url('http://www.example.foobar')

test_url_listed = False
for link in list_of_urls:
    if str(test_url) == str(link):
        test_url_listed = True

if not test_url_listed:
    list_of_urls.append(test_url)
```

Is it possible to make it closer in structure to the following?

```
if test_url not in list_of_urls:
    list_of_urls.append(test_url)
```

(As is, this fails since it compares the objects and not the strings they represent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if str(test_url) not in [str(url) for url in list_of_urls]
```

Or better yet, implement [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) and/or [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) + [`__ne__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) on the url class. (And probably also [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).) Then you could create a `set` of urls which would automatically ensure there are no duplicate urls.

Comment: I was thinking more of how to implement it within a class, which the latter part of this solution does. Got my code working using `__eq__`.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to implement the `__cmp__` method.

```
class url(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
       self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.address, other.address)


list_of_urls = [url('http://www.example.foo'), url('http://www.example.bar')]
test_url = url('http://www.example.foobar')
```

This in:

```
if test_url not in list_of_urls:
    print("Not in")
```

prints "Not in".

Alternatively you can use "rich" comparisons, but that's a little more effort. The `total_ordering` class method can help.

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class url(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
       self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.address == other.address

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.address < other.address
```

This makes all comparisons work with the string attribute named "address". This will fail if you compare other objects, however.

Comment: `__cmp__` is obsolete, and does work in [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons). In 3.2+ `functools.total_ordering` is an easy way to get those all comparisons for free. In previous versions, it's still only a one-liner each (only one oneliner if you only want equality and inequality).

Comment: @delnan True. Edited by adding that alternative.